# Não consigo por chave estrangeira no PHPMYADMIN

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, chave-estrangeira

Tenho meu banco já criado no phpmyadmin, são duas tabelas, pagamentos e alunos.
Eu vi vários tutoriais e li vários jeitos de como colocar uma chave estrangeira (`fk_alunos`) do id_alunos na minha tabela pagamentos , nada dá certo.

**Tabela `pagamentos`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `horus`.`pagamentos` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `situacao_aluno` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `validade_plano` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `planos` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `vencimento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `cpf_amigo` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `forma_pagamento` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `data_matricula` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `numero_documento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `data_documento` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `valor` VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  `status` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `status_mensalidade` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `alunos_id` INT(11) NOT NULL )
```

**Tabela `alunos`**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `horus`.`alunos` (
 `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nome` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `cpf` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `rg` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `nascimento` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `sexo` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `fone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `endereco` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `bairro` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `cep` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 `estado` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 `cidade` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `cpf` (`cpf` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `rg` (`rg` ASC))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
 AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Na tabela pagamentos eu coloquei mais um campo sendo o `id_alunos`
Nos índices da tabela pagamentos acrescentei o nome da chave `fk_alunos`, coluna `id_pagamentos`.

Depois disso, quando tento executar o código "`ALTER TABLE pagamentos ADD CONSTRAINT fk_alunos FOREIGN KEY(id_alunos) REFERENCES alunos (id_alunos)`", só me trás erros dizendo :

> " #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (`horus`.`#sql-32d0_181`, CONSTRAINT `id_alunos` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`id_alunos`) REFERENCES `alunos` (`id_alunos`)) "

Tentei fazer modelo de relacionamento pelo workbench para depois importar para o phpmyadmin, mas nem assim a chave estrangeira aparece.

Comment: E já existem registros nas tabelas? A chave estrangeira pode ser nula? Coloque na pergunta a definição de ambas as tabelas, por favor.

Comment: já existem sim registros...

Answer (score 2):

Simples: `REFERENCES alunos (id_alunos)` está incorreto pois a tabela `alunos` não tem uma coluna chamada `id_alunos`. Acredito que o correto seria `REFERENCES alunos (id)`.

Outro detalhe é que você possui `alunos_id` na sua tabela **pagamentos** enquanto você referencia a coluna `id_alunos`, que não existe, na sua FK.

Comment: ah desculpe meu erro, na verdade existe sim....eu que não alterei ...

     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `horus`.`alunos` (
      `id_alunos` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `nome` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     `cpf` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     `rg` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
      ....etc

Comment: mesmo assim o erro permanece..

Comment: Você utiliza `id_alunos` e `alunos_id`, isso pode estar ocasionando o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Galera consegui achar a solução! Obrigada a todos...

O erro era porque meu phpmyadmin não estava atualizado, nem sequer o desenho da chave estrangeira aparecia....
Acabei remontando a tabela pagamentos novamente escrevendo no SQL e mencionando a foreign key lá mesmo!

Obrigada a todos.